# TableLayoutPanel issue, when adding new items to it

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I'm working on a code that has a function that returns a list. The function is called: MedTuboFunc.

When I click a button, I want the values of the list, added to a TableLayoutPanel.

The code I'm using right now is the following:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 

    Dim lbl As New Label
    Dim a As New List(Of Decimal)
    a = MedTuboFunc()
    For i = 0 To a.Count - 1
        lbl.Text = a(i)
        MessageBox.Show(lbl.Text)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, i)
    Next
End Sub
```

The MessageBox was to see if I was retrieving the values of the list properly. The problem is that the program adds the first value of the list in the position 0,0 in the TableLayoutPanel, but then, when it adds the second one, right below the first one, the first one disappears, and so on.
At the end, I end up with only the last value on the list, while the others are blank.

Thank you for all your help in advance.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Language: Visual Basic.

Comment: You only create a single label and just change the Text.  Move `Dim lbl As New Label` *inside* the loop so you are actually creating as many new labels as you need

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! That fixed the problem!

Is there a way to mark your comment as "The answer"?.